# CKeditor multiple version conflict in SPFX Accordion Webpart on Modern Sharepoint Online page

Tags: sharepoint, ckeditor, sharepoint-online, sharepointframework

I have built an accordion spfx webpart for our Modern Sharepoint site where I am consuming CKeditor version 4.13.0 (Full) CDN version to add Rich text for each accordion tab when the page is in edit mode. It is working perfectly with all the plugins until we add an OOTB Text webpart which is also using Ckeditor 4.13.0 but Standard version. IT overrides the plugins and replaces my Full version to standard which results in loss of functionalities as well as CKEditor dialog also stops working.

Using iframes for my webpart or changing global variable (CKEDITOR) is not a feasible workaround for me. Is there any way to avoid this version conflict in Sharepoint modern page or should I use a different editor for my webpart.